# Best way to pass variable to remote (Golang) app from Django View

Tags: django, go, django-rest-framework, microservices

I'm creating a Django web application that'll assist in barebone server deployments, where a bare bone server will PXE boot to a custom LiveCD to send a cURL command to register itself to a DRF REST API.

When Django receives the `POST` request it'll start a Go app remotely that'll find the bare bone server based on entries in the REST API then start configuring the server. What would be the best way to identify/introduce the bare bone server to my Go server?

My thought is either to use a parser parameter to identify the server then Go will pull the bare bone server info from the REST API or add a Boolean field in the REST API and the Go app will look for entries that are TRUE then flip it to FALSE when it starts setting up the bare bone server.

Would that be the best way to get this done or is there a better way?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking how to parse parameters in the GET/POST request to a Go server?

Comment: No, I plan on using ssh2-python or paramiko to send the remote command. I just wasn't sure if it was a good idea/best way (efficiently) to use a parse parameter in this kind of setup. Another thought was to have a 'ready' Boolean field in the DB and the Go app will start executing on what is TRUE, but if I have dozens of True entries that might cause some anomalies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, PXELINUX comes with an identification mechanism based on the systems MAC dress and the configuration can be customized accordingly. Since you need to do accounting of your bare metal servers anyway (port security anyone? ;) ), you should know the MAC dresses of all the interfaces on your bare metal servers anyway.

Your directory usually looks like this (path prefix may be different).

```
/srv/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/default
```

Now what happens is that your system starts up, sends a DHCP Request and gets an offer containing the DHCP options "next-server" and "filename". When the system selects said offer, it will connect to the "next-server" and request "filename", usually `pxelinux.0`. Here is your first potential hook: Write a tftp server which deals with the request and registers your system.

Now `pxelinux.0` is executed , it will read the above config file. But here is the thing: Say the Mac address of the system is `23:67:33:5a:cc:e8`, and the file

```
/srv/pxe/pxelinux.cfg/23-67-33-5a-cc-e8
```

exists, this will be read instead. Which is your second hook: the request will be logged by tftp.

Regardless of wether the `default` or a system specific config file is used, basically we are talking of GRUB config file. Assuming you use Kickstart to install the system, it will look something like this

```
default linux
prompt 0
timeout 1
label linux
        kernel /images/yourdistro/vmlinuz
        ipappend 2
        append initrd=/images/yourdistro/initrd.img console=ttyS0,115200
```

Now, here is the thing: you have several possibilities to execute a custom program on boot:

- Append the path to your executable to the `append` parameter. By convention, the Kernel will send all parameters it does not know to pid 1. Though I have not tested wether systemd adheres to the convention and simply executes a parameter it does not know in turn, I assume as much.
- cron. Most cron implementations nowadays support the `@boot` time definition.
- the init system, be it either systemd or openrc or good ol' SYSV init.

Last but not least, how to configure the machine. I strongly suggest against reinventing the wheel. I had quite similar requirements in a (closed source) project. We used kickstart to do the basic system installation and simply shot a [curl command after reboot](https://bitraboy.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/how-to-run-an-install-script-after-reboot-centos-rhel/) to [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/products/tower/editions), triggering the more detailed configuration. Since we had a DHCP server with the MAC, an IP reserved for said MAC and a hostname readily configured (dnsmasq, caugh, caugh), that was not much of a problem. Basically, all we had to do manually is to register the MAC address and assign an IP and a hostname, then fire up the machine.